# Android Gallery widget using images from SDcard

Tags: android, gallery, thumbnails

I am trying to display thumbnails stored in a specific folder for my app. These are downloaded when the app is running. I am using the gallery widget to show the thumbnails which I read from the SDcard when the getView() of the ImageAdapter is called but when I swipe(scroll) on the widget. Firstly the scroll is not smooth its almost like I shivering to scroll and scrolls very erratically. Is there an efficient way of doing this. I tried storing the thumbnails in memory the scrolling is smooth but I know i will run into memory issues if I have more thumbnails ..

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache images to memory using something like a HashMap and them when your application is running out of memory your [Activity.onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onLowMemory%28%29) will be called. Implement this method and clear all images that aren't being shown to the user right now.

Also, you could use [Activity.onTrimMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTrimMemory%28int%29) instead of onLowMemory.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can use GridView and Custom ImageAdapter. 
and for Thumbnails you can directly use MediaStore image thumbnails. and there is no memory related issue.

```
final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(                          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ?",  new String[] {file.getAbsoluteFile().toString()}, orderBy);

int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);   
imagecursor.moveToPosition(0);
int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);                
thumbnails = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(                 getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
iv.setImageBitmap(thumbnails);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response . But I want to use the gallery widget and I want to show only images related to my app. MediaStore will show all images on SD card right ?